# Extra space after hide the first section in a Form in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need to hide/show the Sections in a `Form`, I did the following code which works fine for all Sections except the first one, after I hide and show again the first `Section` there is an extra space at the top, see the gif bellow, any idea why this happens ?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var visible = true

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            visible ? Section(header: Text("label")) {
                        Text("text")
                    } : nil
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    self.visible.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text("hide/show text")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to use visual debugger? what is there when you try to debug it?

Comment: It’s just section header for the section which contains the button.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa I'm saing about the space above "label"

Comment: @Lu_ I tried, it's nothing there, just an empty space above the first Section's header

Comment: This is almost certainly a bug. SwiftUI is still new, and I have noticed several little things like this with List, Form, etc. Best bet is the file feedback with Apple: http://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: Sections in grouped tables have a bit of empty space above the label, if you change from Form to List the empty space will disappear

Comment: Try with `Spacer()` and set position with `frames`.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug, it is fixed on ios 14.